# Тема WP подкладывает непрозрачный фон под мою прозрачную png картинку

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

[надо заменить белый на прозрачный](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhDce.png) Хочу сделать параллакс из 2х картинок. Задняя картинка(далее img1) уже есть и относительно скрола стоит на месте (position: fixed). На переднем плане полупрозрачная картинка(далее img2) должна двигаться в стандартном потоке и наезжать поверх фиксированной картинки(img1). Проблема в том, что тема астро подкладывает ещё один НЕ прозрачный фон под картинку2(img2).

Как я это понял - я взял картинку2(img2) и через дев тул сместил вниз страницы и убедился что она сохранила свою полупрозрачность, а на её бывшем месте остался белый фон.
Отключил через дев тулс все стили - не помогло
Перезаписал все белые цвета, чтобы вычислить откуда берётся этот стиль - не помогло
Перезаписал для всех родительских тегов через девтулс стили на bacground-color: transparent - не помогло! Помогите сделать прозрачный фон у картинки2 (img2)
[image: стандарные стили темы астро на wp]
[image: вырвал из потока, чтобы проверить прозрачность заднего плана]
домен https://professional-kurs.ru/

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Может это у body белый фон? Или как по вашему должен выглядеть "прозрачный" фон страницы?

Comment: Да, вы правы. Но у меня появляется следующий вопрос - почему img1 сайт через админку ставить ПОД body а img2 НАД body ?

Comment: Если бы обе картинки были поверх тега body, тогда проблемы изначально не было! https://ibb.co/hVR86JX (скриншот добавления бэкграундов через админку)

Comment: @Alex  Что в Вашем понимании значит "под body"? Вы же имеете ввиду явно не z-index.

Comment: я имел ввиду как отображаются слои на самой странице визуально и визуально я подсветил тег бади цветом аква. Видно что под бади лежит img1 и имеет белый фон (стили браузера по умолчанию)

Comment: и ещё меня смущает что для img1, img2 не работает z-index в девтулс. Не знаете почему так происходит? Например я хочу поднять img1 над img2 и задаю <img1 {z-index: 9999;}> <img2 {z-index: 1;}>  и ничего не происходит! Впервые с таким сталкиваюсь

Comment: @Alex ну да, у секции с классами `ast-primary-header-bar ast-primary-header main-header-bar site-header-focus-item` белый фон, который можно поменять на transparent или что Вам нужно и что дальше? Просто изначально вообще не понятно чего Вы пытаетесь добиться.

Comment: Да, именно это мне и нужно! Но для этих классов не удаётся заменить белый фон, на прозрачный. Может я ошибку в коде делаю? Записал видео с результатом, который хочу видеть https://youtu.be/i_Ptsav8bPw

Comment: анимированный результат параллакса https://youtu.be/Uf0yKuzu2f4